# Django finds tests but fail to import them

Tags: python, django, testing

I am getting weird errors, where a call to `./manage.py test` will find my tests but complain that they cannot be imported.

### Versions

Python 3.4

Django 1.7b4

### My file structure

looks like this (just the relevant bits):

```
inkasso
├── db.sqlite3
├── functional_tests
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── base.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── test_login.py
│   └── test_login.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── inkasso
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── ...
├── templates
│   ├── ...
└── web
    ├── admins.py
    ├── tests
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test_forms.py
    │   ├── test_models.py
    │   └── test_views.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

### The stack-trace

So when I run `./manage.py test` I get the following stak-trace:

```
 $ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
EEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: inkasso.functional_tests.test_login (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 57, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 574, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: inkasso.functional_tests.test_login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'inkasso.functional_tests'


======================================================================
ERROR: inkasso.web.tests.test_forms (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 57, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 574, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: inkasso.web.tests.test_forms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'inkasso.web'


======================================================================
ERROR: inkasso.web.tests.test_models (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 57, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 574, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: inkasso.web.tests.test_models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'inkasso.web'


======================================================================
ERROR: inkasso.web.tests.test_views (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 57, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 574, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: inkasso.web.tests.test_views
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'inkasso.web'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=4)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So the test runner finds my tests, but for some reason, they are not imported. I have no idea what it is going on. The stack-trace is not very helpful to me :(

Since the root folder is called `inkasso` and it has a module of the same name, I tried putting `print(os.getcwd)` and `print(sys.path)` into manage.py, and all it showed was that CWD and path was both set to point at the root folder, so it should be all good, no? The app itself runs as expected. It is only the tests that are not working.

For giggles, I tried creating an empty module 'web' in inkasso.inkasso, with the result that instead of complaining that inkasso.web doesn't exist, it now complains that inkasso.web.tests does not exist. So this shows that instead of looking in the root 'inkasso' folder, it looks in 'inkasso.inkasso'. So that is the issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeah... there's a problem with running `./manage.py`, in that it adds the current directory to the PYTHONPATH.

This problem happens when you put an `__init__.py` inside the root folder.

One solution would be, in this case, to never use `manage.py`, but only `django-admin.py <commands> --settings=inkasso.inkasso.settings` - of course, this assumes either that when running this command, you're one level up, outside your root folder `inkasso`, or you have your main package installed in `site-packages`.

For example, if the complete path to your `settings.py` file is `/home/user/projects/inkasso/inkasso/settings.py`, you need to be in `/home/user/projects` when running this command.

If however you've got your package installed inside your site-packages, the above restriction changes: you can be anywhere except `/home/user/projects/inkasso` or any of its subfolders or so on.

Another solution is to edit your `manage.py` file to add this line:

```
if __name__ =='__main__': #line already present
    #this will make the python interpreter see your packages as inkasso.inkasso.whatever
    os.chdir('..')  # <<<---This is what you want to add

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mvod.dev_settings")
    ....
```

Comment: I deleted ./__init__.py, and now the unit tests are run poperly. The functional tests still fail, but that seems to be due to selenium having syntax not valid in python3. Thanks for the assistace :)

Comment: Thanks, was really annoyed with this problem.

Comment: Dude, you are an absolute lifesaver.  I added a root dunder-init at some point and it broke 100+ tests, and it took me a month to find this thread.

Have an e-beer on me!

Comment: Changing directory for all commands seems to stop the 'runserver' command from working. It is frustrating that the recommended commands don't work even when you follow all of the guidelines.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 well django is for developers. I guess a lot of times people just figure out the stuff that's not quite work out of the box. When they don't, there's the internet :)